# Unpack aab resources.pb

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, decompiler

I have the .aab that I'm planning to upload on play store for publish, and before publishing I'm trying a decompile to see which data may be exposed to user in a reverse engineering process.

In .aab_FILES/base/ I see the assets.pb and resources.pb protobuffs - can these files be open some in some way? Cause for the moment I haven't found any method to reveal their content.

I am actually looking to see where are values/strings.xml packed - cause they are missing from .aab_FILES/base/res/ location and I wanna make sure my maps API key (which resides in strings.xml) won't be exposed to users.

Comment: Yes, would really like someone give an answer. I've looked a lot of time today without result.

Answer (score 2):

The resources.pb is a serialization of the strings data, so they can't be directly extracted to xml.

There are 2 ways to go around this:

### Convert from aab to apk

Use [bundletool](https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases) to convert the aab to a universal apk and read the xmls from there:

```
java -jar bundletool-all-1.8.0.jar build-apks --mode=universal --bundle=~/test.aab --output=~/universal.apks
```

The universal.apks file can now be unzipped. It contains a universal.apk file, which the resources can be taken from like any apk. The easiest way to get readable xml files from the apk is by using [apktool](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/releases/tag/v2.6.0):

```
apktool d ~/unzipped_universal_apks/universal.apk -o ~/unzipped_universal
```

The folder ~/unzipped_universal now contains the decoded universal.apk and the xml resources should be decoded and readable inside it.

### Read the protobuf values directly from the protobuf file

In order to read a protobuf file, you need its scheme (or proto file).
The proto files for an aab are in the [aapt2](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/tools/aapt2) repository:
[Resources.proto](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/tools/aapt2/Resources.proto) which depends on [Configuration.proto](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/tools/aapt2/Configuration.proto).

These files can be compiled to workable code in a number of programming languages. I'll show it using python as described [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial).

First though, the Resources.proto should be modified to import Configuration.proto from the same folder location instead of the original (unless you create the whole necessary folder structure).

So, change:

```
import "frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/Configuration.proto";
```

To:

```
import "Configuration.proto";
```

Now, in the terminal, run:

```
protoc  --python_out=~/proto_output Configuration.proto Resources.proto
```

Inside ~/proto_output there will now be 2 files: Configuration_pb2.py   Resources_pb2.py.
These files contain the python code to access the protobuf structure for the resources.pb file, as well as the protobuf encoded AndroidManifest.xml.

In order to read the protobuf file run:

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict
from Resources_pb2 import ResourceTable

res_obj = ResourceTable()
res_pb_file_path = '~/unzipped_app_bundle/base/resources.pb'
with open(res_pb_file_path, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
res_obj.ParseFromString(content)

# converting the protobuf object to a nice dictionary representation
res_dict = MessageToDict(res_obj)
```

Comment: How to run this from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict
from Resources_pb2 import ResourceTable

res_obj = ResourceTable()
res_pb_file_path = '~/unzipped_app_bundle/base/resources.pb'
with open(res_pb_file_path, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
res_obj.ParseFromString(content)

# converting the protobuf object to a nice dictionary representation
res_dict = MessageToDict(res_obj)  in terminal or in python file can you explain this part in detail ?

Comment: @Maveňツ put that code in a python file and change res_pb_file_path to your resources.pb file. Then just look at the res_dict. What exactly are you having trouble with? Bte, you can also use aapt2 to read the resources. But not in xml format.

Comment: Can you please edit and add your complete answer here?

Comment: It really is as complete as can be imo. Unless you can tell me what you think is missing.

Comment: I want to read resources.pb file make changes in it and repack it back to binary format. As per you solution I have got readable format of resources.pb  file but unable to make it back as binary.

Comment: @Maveňツ that's quite different unfortunately. for that you need to modify the res_obj itself, not the res_dict. this isn't straightforward. most values also have a compiled_item.prim value that needs to be set aside from the actual node value. and if you're setting a reference value, it's different than just a string value. it's a topic unto itself.
i suggest you look at the res_dict, and see how it is changes after changing a value in your app and build it. then do these changes on your res_obj and finally, you'll need to call res_obj.SerializeToString() and write the output back to file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I have tried the first method and done with `apk` generation successfully but I have a requirement of bundle file decompile unfortunately, I am new to `protobuf` and python so unable to proceed further into this. I would be happy if you share some code snippets in your answer, as that would help future (community members) readers to solve this complex problem of android bundle file decompilation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this given de-compile jar BundleDecompiler

de-compile option:

```
java -jar BundleDecompiler.jar decompile  --in=input_app.aab   --out=output_dir
```